# Loading XML data from SQL Server directly into MarkLogic?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, nosql

Has anyone loaded XML data from SQL Server to a MarkLogic document store? This would be preferable to dumping XML to file system and then using mlcp.

Maybe with SSIS?

Comment: Knowing nothing of MarkLogic, I find it's helpful to restate questions without an emphasis on a particular technology. Thus, "how can I load data directly into MarkLogic" If you have the answer to that, then it becomes easy to swap in data sourced from SQL Server and possibly using SSIS as the conduit for moving the data. That said, SSIS has no native connectors for MarkLogic.

Answer (score 1):

JShean,

I am with the MarkLogic product team, I saw your question and wanted to point you to some information.  In general, mlcp is the most efficient way to load documents into MarkLogic, though I know many customers don't like dumping all the data to disk.

Have you considered doing the process in batch - dump a certain set to disk, use mlcp to load and repeat?

The alternative is to use the REST API and batch write documents to Marklogic.  I have included a few links to our documentation.

**Introduction to REST API**

docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro

**Manipulating Documents (general summary)**

docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents

**Reading and Writing Multiple Documents**

docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk

If you have additional questions, you can reach me at susan.lee@marklogic.com.

Thanks, and have a GREAT day!

susan.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I currently use mlcp for the load.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of experimentation with non-relational datastores and found the integration tooling is usually poor or non-existant. It's probably more productive to approach this as a pull from the MarkLogic side than as a push from the SSIS side.